# DDD value object with reference to entity identifier

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

In Domain Driven Design(DDD) a ValueObject has the following definition

> A Value Object is an object that describes some characteristic or
>   attribute but carries no concept of identity.

Lets say I have 'Client' entity and an 'Order' entity. Orders are related to Clients, so normally I would add field ClientId in the Order class, because I may not reference the Client entity itself. So far so good...

Now I wonder if it is oke to create a value object ClientInfo, which will include the name of the client, the client status, **but also the ClientId**? ClientInfo would be immutable with only getters for clientName, clientStatus and clientId.

So there you have it, a value object with an entity identifier. Is this against the definition of a value object, or am I safe here?

Comment: I don't think that this question is a duplicate of the referenced question. Here, the OP asks specifically about IDs within value objects, not about the general concepts of entities / value objects.

Comment: This indeed is not a duplicate of referred question, but more specifically  targeted to the Value Object and its constraints. The definition talks about ValueObject not having the concept of identity, which means the ValueObject should not have an ID representing the ValueObject. However, the ValueObject may contain identfiers referring to entities

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A value object with a reference to an entity identifier is fine. If you had two ClientInfo objects with the same information in, they would be completely interchangeable. They are values just like Strings or integers.

Comment: its fine, but its not a value object

Comment: It is a value object! It does not have identity of its own, it contains a value representing the identity of an entity.

Comment: a value representing the ID, is still an ID, its uniquely tied to a client, it does not just represent values.

Comment: I disagree, using your rules a value object can look the same as an entity or domain object ...

Comment: You are getting confused because it relates to identifiers. Think of it this way: Does the calling code expect a *specific instance* or does it not care about which instance it gets, only the value?

Comment: but the definition given (and wdiely used), shows that it is any "concept of ID" not just the specific instance. The value object is tied to a specific instance, its not just values.

Comment: It doesn't have any concept of identity! It stores an identity reference! If you stored an ID in a String, is that String a value object or an entity? It's a value object of course.

Comment: Wow, I read the same discussion as I had in my mind ;-) I was already leaning towards what aetheria is saying, so thanks for confirming my thoughts! :)